# Is there any way plot (x and Y) for each value of a variable (country) for a time series (2000 -2100)?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to plot the 28 charts (one per country ['ctr']) representing the x and y for the time series from 2000 - 2100.

Here below is my table:

[table: countries, year and x and y varibales](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z05hS.png)

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4vJh.png]

What I did was: I created 308 plots one (empty) for each value of the table - one plot for year for each country.

What I want is: 28 plots (one per country) for X and Y values of the time series 2000-2100.

```
X = df.iloc[:, -1].values
y = df_1.iloc[:, -2].values
for i in df['CNT']:
       plt.figure()
       plt.plot(X[i],y[i])
       plt.show()
```

Since  I am not able to group the column countries ['CNT'] by countries, i am not able to create one plot for the country, instead I am creating a plot for each row of the table.

I would appreciate very much someone help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to extract subset of your dataframe based on unique countries.
Use these subsets to plot the graphs per country.

```
for country in df.CNT.unique():
    temp_df = df[df.CNT == country]
    temp_df.plot(x='x', y='y')
```